# getting in-process queues in twilio

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-functions

Is there any way to get Queues which have `current_size` greater than 0.

I want to get Queues which have `current_size` greater than 0, I have hundreds of Queues in the system so i want to get only specific queues.

This is what i have done. I am getting the queues having `current_size` 0.

```
function get_inprocess_queue_calls(){
   if(!$this->input->is_ajax_request()){
        exit('Direct access of script is not allowed');
    }
    require_once 'twilio/Twilio.php';
    $twilio_result=$this->broswer_call_model->twilio_credentials();
    $client = new Services_Twilio($twilio_result->twilio_accountId, $twilio_result->twilio_authtoken);
    $queues = $client->account->queues->getIterator(0, 50,array("Status" => "in-progress")); 
    $i=0;
    $data='';
    foreach ($queues as $queue) { 
        if($queue->current_size>0){
            $f_name = $queue->friendly_name;
            if($f_name!=''){
                $nameArr = array();
                $nameArr = @explode('_', $f_name);
                $leadId = $nameArr[3];
                $from_number = $nameArr[0];
                if(strpos($from_number, '+')!== false){
                    $lead_name = '';
                    if($leadId!=0){
                        $lead_record = $this->broswer_call_model->get_lead_details($leadId,$this->teamId,$this->leadTable);
                        if($lead_record!=0){
                            $lead_name = $lead_record->first_name.' '.$lead_record->last_name;
                        }
                    }
                    $fun_param1 = "'".$queue->friendly_name."'";
                    $fun_param2 = "'".$queue->sid."'";
                    $data.='<tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">'.$lead_name.'</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">'.$from_number.'</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">'.$queue->average_wait_time.'</td>
                        <td onclick="ConnectLead('.$fun_param1.','.$fun_param2.')" style="cursor:pointer; color:#0066FF; text-align: center;">Connect</td>
                    </tr>';
                }
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode(array('show_status'=>$i,'data'=>$data)); 
}
```

What I want to do is like

`$queues = $client->account->queues->getIterator(0, 50,array("Status" => "in-progress"));`

Or like

`$queues = $client->account->queues->getIterator(0, 50,array("Current Size" => "> 0"));`

Any Help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [documentation for the Queues resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/queue#queues-list-resource) only lists `FriendlyName` and `MaxSize` as the parameters you can use to filter the results. This doesn't include a status parameter or current length parameter, so there is no direct call you can make to the API for this.

It looks like what you've got is probably your best bet now.